# React Router v6: Route tracking with matchRoutes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

We used our own in-house Route-component to track routes in `react-router-dom` v5. It looked roughly like this:

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

// EDIT: This was React-Router v5 code, in v6 <Switch> is replaced by <Routes>
//       and <Route component={}> is replaced by <Route element={}>

const routes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <TrackedRoute title="title to track" path="/path/home" component={Home} />
    <TrackedRoute title="title to track" path="/path/contact" component={Contact} />
  </Switch>
)

const TrackedRoute = ({ title, ...others }) => {
  doTrackingThings(title);
  return (
    <Route {...others} />
  );
}
```

But in React Router v6 the Routes component only accepts its own `<Route>` objects. This is enforced through type equality. Additionally optional params are no longer allowed in route paths, which made our tracking more complicated. If we want to track which route the user is on, how do we do this in React Router v6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up moving the tracking to a separate component. It looks roughly like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, matchRoutes, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const app = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/path/home" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/path/contact" element={<Contact />} />
    </Routes>
    <RouteTracker />
  </BrowserRouter>
);

const RouteTracker = () => {
  // Add our tracking, find all routes that match and track it
  const currentLocation = useLocation();
  const someRoutes = [
    { path: "/path/home" },
    { path: "/path/contact" },
  ];
  const matches = matchRoutes(someRoutes, currentLocation);
  doTrackingThings(matches);
  return null;
}
```

We wanted to do tracking in one single location (the app is large). For someone else having a `<Tracked>` component like the other answers suggest may be a better fit.

Comment: I think you have a typo - Route in v6 does not have component props. Should it be element instead?

Answer (score 1):

I would make a component e.g. Tracked and wrap in it element itself:

```js
const Tracked = ({title, children})=>{
 doTrackingThings(title);
 return children
}

//then

<Routes>
  <Route path="/home" element={<Tracked title='home'><Home/></Tracked>}/>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Switch` is changed as `Routes` in v6. As we have nested elements , we can return the `props` of children to parent.

```
const Tracked = ({title, children})=>{
 // use title here
 return children // as props for the parent 
}
```

Call it as:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/home" element={<Tracked title='title'><Home/></Tracked>}/>
</Routes>
```